# EventTarget.addEventListener()'s useCapture argument use?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am studying the vanilla JavaScript and I have some trouble understanding what is the use of this `useCapture` argument in the `EventTarget.addEventListener()` function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

> **useCapture** Optional
>
> If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate capture. After initiating capture, all events of the specified type
>   will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched
>   to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree. Events which are
>   bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener
>   designated to use capture. See DOM Level 3 Events and JavaScript Event
>   order for a detailed explanation. If not specified, useCapture
>   defaults to false.

Reading it's doc, I've got confused from the first sentence. And
trying to understand it I've setup a little test page with three nested elements, with a click listener on the two top most div.

The code :

```js
var treeTopEl = document.getElementById('container');
var treeMiddleEl = document.getElementById('wrapper');

var output = document.getElementById('output');

var treeTopElListener = function(event){
 var elId = event.target.id;
 output.innerHTML += "\nListener on the top element was triggerd,\n\t The event target id is : "+elId; 
};

var treeMiddleElListener = function(event){
 var elId = event.target.id;
 output.innerHTML += "\nListener on the middle element was triggerd,\n\tThe event target id is : "+elId; 
};

treeTopEl.addEventListener('click', treeTopElListener, false);
treeMiddleEl.addEventListener('click', treeMiddleElListener, true);
```

```css
#container, #wrapper {
  padding : 20px;
  border : 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="wrapper">
   <button id="testBtn">A button</button>

 </div>
</div>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

#### The question :

When you click the button both listeners are triggered <strike>in the same order</strike> no matter of the `useCapture` configuration : both `true`; both `false`; first one `true`, second one `false`; first one `false`, second one `true`.

What exactly captures `useCapture` flag ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this diagram from [the DOM events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) pretty much says it all:

[image]

Basically: The `useCapture` argument is used to receive notification during the capture phase, rather than the bubbling phase. A capturing-phase handler will be called before **any** bubbling-phase handler. Note that Internet Explorer didn't support the capturing phase prior to IE9.

So a better example is two handlers on the same element, in the middle (but let's do all three levels for completeness):

```js
hook("container", "- ");
hook("wrapper",   "&nbsp;&nbsp;- ");
hook("testBtn",   "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- ");

function hook(id, prefix) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    display(id + "'s capturing handler called", prefix);
  }, true);
  element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    display(id + "'s bubbling called", prefix);
  }, false);
}

function display(msg, prefix) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = (prefix || "") + msg;
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

```css
#container, #wrapper {
  padding : 10px;
  border : 1px solid green;
}
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="wrapper">
   <button id="testBtn">A button</button>
 </div>
</div>
```